# How can I minimize boilerplate code associated with std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I have several classes like this in my C++ code:

```
class ThreadRunner {
public:
    void start() {
        m_thread = std::thread(&ThreadRunner::runInThread, this);
    }
    void stop() {
        m_terminate = true;
    }
    ~ThreadRunner() {
        m_terminate = true;
        if (m_thread.joinable()) {
            m_thread.join();
        }
    }

private:
    void runInThread() {
        size_t i = 0;
        while (!m_terminate) {
            std::cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
            i++;
        }
    };
    std::thread          m_thread;
    std::atomic<bool> m_terminate{ false };
};
```

Some of my `runInThread` functions take arguments, and some do not.
There is quite a bit of boilerplate code (m_terminate, join) that I have to repeat for each class.
All this is of course motivated by that I do not want terminate to get called inside destructor of `std::thread`:

```
~thread() noexcept {
   if (joinable()) {
      _STD terminate();
   }
}
```

A colleague has made a class encapsulating this boilerplate.
The way it works is that it has a `virtual void runInThread() = 0` method.
So each of my classes would inherit this baseclass and override this method.
Also there is an implicit assumption that each override checks `m_terminate` occasionally.

I would prefer to use composition instead of inheritance.
That is MyClass uses a MyThread not is a MyThreadObject.
How can I create a start method that takes a "function pointer" and arbitrary arguments and passes them on to std::thread constructor?

If it is too much hassle I guess I could will go with my colleague's approach instead. From what I understand Java has a Runnable interface where one must override `void Run()`.

If I were to use `std::jthread` is this how it should be done?

```
class ThreadRunner {
public:
    void start() {
        m_thread = std::jthread(&ThreadRunner::runInThread, this, m_stop_source.get_token());
    }
    void stop() {
        m_stop_source.request_stop();
    }
    ~ThreadRunner() {
        stop(); // otherwise ~jthread waits forever for runInThread to finish
    }
private:
    void runInThread(std::stop_token stoken) {
        size_t i = 0;
        while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
            std::cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
            i++;
        }
    };
    std::jthread          m_thread;
    std::stop_source m_stop_source;
};
```

What are the benefits of using a `std::stop_source` over a `std::atomic<bool> m_terminate`?

If I were to use `std::async` is this how it would be done?:

```
class ThreadRunner {
public:
    void start() {
        m_future = std::async(std::launch::async, &ThreadRunner::runInThread, this);
    }
    void stop() {
        m_terminate = true;
    }
    ~ThreadRunner() {
        stop();
    }
private:
    void runInThread() {
        size_t i = 0;
        while (!m_terminate) {
            std::cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
            i++;
        }
    };
    std::future<void> m_future;
    std::atomic<bool> m_terminate{ false };
};
```

Comment: Pass a `std::function<void()>` to your class and use it, that's about equivalent to the `Runnable` interface in Java except it's not named.

Comment: you could use [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread)

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Thank you. It seems jthread 1/2 the boilerplate code. I still have to stop the thread in the destructor?
Do I also need a std::stop_source member variable? There is a method: jthread::get_stop_token(). But how can I call this as an argument to the jthread being constructed?

Comment: no, `jthread`'s destructor calls stop and then join. There is an example of stopping in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token)

Comment: You can avoid `joinable` hassle by using `std::async` instead. Personally, I almost always use it instead of `std::thread`. Then, not sure if this is the full code of your `ThreadRunner`, but have in mind that calling `start` twice will result in `std::terminate`.

Comment: @pptaszni: I still have to use a std::atomic<bool> m_terminate flag and set this to true in the destructor in order to cancel the thread when my program exits? See my final code block above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `std::jthread` code can be simplified to:

```
class ThreadRunner {
public:
    void start() {
        m_thread = std::jthread(&ThreadRunner::runInThread, this);
    }
    void stop() {
        m_thread.request_stop();
    }
private:
    void runInThread() {
        size_t i = 0;
        auto stopToken = m_thread.get_stop_token();
        while (!stopToken.stop_requested()) {
            std::cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
            i++;
        }
    };
    std::jthread          m_thread;
};
```

Or as your wrapper isn't doing much just using `std::jthread` directly might be simpler:

```
std::jthread thread([](std::stop_token stoken){
    size_t i = 0;
    while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
        std::cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I tried  your version of  ThreadRunner above on Visual Studio 2019 with compiler flag: /std:c++20 but unfortunately it did not work.
I waited for 1 sec in the main loop and then let the ThreadRunner go out of scope. The code above ran forever.

Comment: @Andy sorry, the token was from the previous instance of `m_thread`, fixed